# How can I consume the results of two coroutines returning two different Result types?

Tags: android, kotlin, reactive-programming, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

- Coroutine 1 returns Result<A>;
- Coroutine 2 returns Result<B>;
- Both results need to map to some kind of UI format, e.g. MenuItem;
- If coroutine 1 fails, the process should terminate and return a UI error state;
- if coroutine 2 fails, it should also terminate the process and return a Ui error state;
- Coroutine failures are indicated by a sort of custom Result.Fail type, and not by throwing exceptions;
- Both coroutine 1 and coroutine 2 have the same error handling, but have different mapping requirements for their success case.

I was thinking of using Kotlin flow, but I'm still getting to grips with reactive programming and wanted to know if this would be a good use case. The main complication is that the fail cases are not indicated by exceptions. Also, I just don't know if this is a good approach. Please be kind!

Something like the following:

```
sealed class UiState {
   data class menuRetrieved(val menu items: List<MenuItem>) : UiState
   object storageError: UiState
   object unknownError: UiState
}

val uiState = flowOf(coroutine1.await(), coroutine2.await())
    .onEach {
       checkIsError(it) // handle potential error cases
    }
    .transformWhile {
        emit(it)
        it is Result.Success<*> 
    }
    .map { result: Result.Success<*> ->
        result.toMenuItem() // some extension function
    }
    .collect()
```

Note that the coroutines are interrogating local storage - e.g. files / shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for zip operator from flow

Eg

```
val flowInt = flowOf(1, 2, 3)
val flowString = flowOf("A", "B", "C")
flowInt.zip(flowString) { intValue, stringValue ->
    "$intValue$stringValue"
}.collect {
    Log.d(TAG, it)
}
```

Combine data from two apis eventually.
Credit [blog](https://blog.mindorks.com/kotlin-flow-zip-operator-parallel-multiple-network-calls)

Comment: Hmm... Not sure how that handles with the error handling.

Comment: Ideally all errors should be catched like this in flow


`.catch {
                            flowCollector -> 
// Handle error with message                               }.collect {
// Handle success
}`

I've seen few errors are not caught in catch {} operator, so we put try catch in the launch block as well.